# Deleted anaconda and now cannot run curl requests

Tags: bash, curl, anaconda

I made a huge mistake and deleted anaconda. I had it in my /Users/me/anaconda and deleted it from there. I also saw when I do the command 'cd//' it is there but there are no files. This is causing a huge issue because I cannot run curl commands. When I try it says "-bash: cd: /Users/me/anaconda/bin/curl: No such file or directory"

I'm not sure what to do and how to fix this problem. It's a little scary :(

Answer (score 0):

Was able to delete anaconda with

```
sudo rm -rf //anaconda
```

Reinstalled and everything was fine